# Benchmark Ubuntu Persistent USB vs Installed System

Tags: usb, live-usb, persistence, benchmarks

Persistent USB's used to be very slow compared to an installed system.

Nowadays Persistent USB's using 18.04 almost seem to be catching up to installed systems in speed, except perhaps when saving data.

I would like to benchmark Persistent USB 2 drives, (including toram), vs Persistent USB 3 drives vs Full install USB 3 drives vs Ubuntu installed on HDD and SSD with 18.04 and 20.04 versions.

So far I have made several runs using *Unixbench* software and the results looked very close when there is lots of RAM.

My question is what benchmark software would give the most useful comparison between USB, HDD and SDD speeds when using Ubuntu on them,?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phoronix Test Suite (PTS) is a free and open-source benchmark software for Linux and other operating systems. The Phoronix Test Suite has been endorsed by sites such as Linux.com, LinuxPlanet and has been called "the best benchmarking platform" by Softpedia. The Phoronix Test Suite is also used by Tom's Hardware, ASELabs and other review sites. - (From Wikipedia).

The Phoronix Test Suite has access to more than 450 test profiles and over 100 test suites. It is enlightening to review some of the benchmark comparisons between Linux distributions and Windows operating systems that have already been completed.

Phoronix Operating Systems Archives: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=category&item=Operating%20Systems

Comment: I am looking forward to detailed results from your benchmarking adventures :-)